# Scrapy: Invalid XPath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

```
hxs.select("//h:h2[re:test(., 'a', 'i')]").extract()


Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/libxml2sel.py", line 44,     in select
raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % xpath)
ValueError: Invalid XPath: //h:h2[re:test(., 'a', 'i')]
```

I'm new to XPath and Scrapy.

What's wrong with it? (I'm trying to select nodes that contain the word "a").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the traceback, you're using an undefined namespace prefix `re`. I'm not familiar with scrapy but it seems you have to define the namespace prefix somewhere.

BTW, isn't the function you're trying to use called [`matches`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches)?

You could call it like this: `//h:h2[matches(., 'a', 'i')]`

An alternative would be
`//h:h2[contains(lower-case(.),'a')]`

Also, what you said (

> What's wrong with it? (I'm trying to select nodes that contain the
>   word "a").

) contradicts the function's semantics. In your snippet, you're actually looking for a string that **contains the letter a**. Not for **a as a word**.

If a is the only text in your element, you could also try using: 
`//h:h2[lower-case(.)='a']`

Or if you're looking for **a** as a word in a longer text, you can combine the use of `matches` with [XPath regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax).